# #define Pre-processor Replacement in Printf() String

Tags: c, string, macros, printf, c-preprocessor

I am printing a string such as:

```
printf("Print the number thirty: 30\n");
```

If I make the following definition

```
#define THIRTY 30
```

and now

```
printf("Print the number thirty: THIRTY");
```

Does the **C** Pre-processor replace `THIRTY --> 30` in the string?

Or do I have to go:

```
printf("Print then number thirty: %d", THIRTY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C Pre-processor doesnot understand what is inside String and hence does not manipulate string.

The below statement will replace `THIRTY` with `30`

```
printf("Print then number thirty: %d", THIRTY);
```

Answer (score 2):

PreProcessor could do it but you must stringfy your define.

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
#define THIRTY 30
#define TEST "Print the number thirty: " xstr(THIRTY) "\n"

int main()
{
    printf(TEST);
    return 0;
}
```

Take a look at [THIS](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Print the number thirty: THIRTY");   // it will consider is whole as a string
```

This will just print `Print the number thirty: THIRTY` in output.

Your second statement -

```
printf("Print then number thirty: %d", THIRTY);  //you probably need this
```

will print - `Print then number thirty:30` as output .

Comment: @LPs  That's not the point . OP wants to know which one will work as he expected . So for that the answer was for.

Comment: The question is Does the C Pre-processor replace THIRTY --> 30 in the string? PreProcessor can to that...

Comment: Will PreProcessor do that with that macro definition ? Then there is need to change the macro definition . And the question was with that macro definition . So no with that definition Preprocessor wont do that .

Comment: @LPs  There are some additional things in your code therefore it will work . But with only `#define THIRTY 30` it wont . I think question address that .

Comment: I guessed, probably I'm wrong, that OP is asking for a way to speed up printf using a preprocessor way that gives a preformatted string. This to avoid printf to evaluate `%d` format.

Comment: @LPs Well,  I guess that was not the question about . But your answer gave a method to in other way  :)